# Is the lacunary series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ bounded along some sequences converging to the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$. Is it possible to have a sequence $z_{n} \in \mathbb{D}$ such that $|z_{n}| \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $|f(z_{n})| \rightarrow M < \infty$?

I know that if $z_{n} = r_{n}e^{i\theta}$ for some fixed $\theta$, the answer is no, but what if $\theta$ varies with $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If there were no sequence $(z_k)$ with $\lvert z_k\rvert \to 1$ and $\lvert f(z_k)\rvert$ bounded, then $f$ would "uniformly approach $\infty$ as $z \to \partial \mathbb{D}$". Then let $P$ be a polynomial having the same zeros (including multiplicity) as $f$ (there are then only finitely many) and consider

$$g(z) = \frac{P(z)}{f(z)}.$$

Since $P$ and $f$ have the same zeros, $g$ is a holomorphic zero-free function on the disk, and since $P(z)$ remains bounded as $\lvert z\rvert\to 1$, it follows that

$$\lim_{\lvert z\rvert\to 1} \lvert g(z)\rvert = 0,$$

but that contradicts the maximum principle. So the assumption that $\lvert f(z)\rvert\to\infty$ for $\lvert z\rvert \to 1$ must have been wrong.

Comment: $f$ needs not to have finitely many zeros. This comes from the fact that $\mathbb D$ is not compact. For example the function $z\mapsto \sin(1/(1-z))$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$, is not identically $0$ and yet has infinitely many $0$ inside $\mathbb D$.

Comment: @Renart But when we assume that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \to +\infty$ as $z \to \partial \mathbb{D}$, it follows that there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f$ has no zeros in the annulus $1-\varepsilon < \lvert z\rvert < 1$, and that implies that $f$ has only finitely many zeros.

Comment: Ah Indeed ! i was wrong and you were right. thanks !

Comment: Wrong is too strong a word. You overlooked a condition, that's all.

Comment: I would like to point out that what Daniel Fischer's proved above is not unique to the particular series ($\sum_n z^{n!}$) in the problem, but that it holds to all analytic functions in the unit circle. See problem 15, chapter 12 in Rudin's real and complex analysis.